# OS X and apps keep forgetting saved credentials and login status

Tags: macos, security

The past couple of weeks, several apps have forgotten stored credentials a number of times:

- Google and iCloud account configured on the Macbook (have had to verify my Google account using 2-step verification for the 2nd time in 30 days)
- Facebook, Stack Exchange et al. keep logging me out (= session cookies seem to get wiped between browser restarts)
- Stored VPN passwords
- Skype

for no apparent reason. I haven't been installing any new apps. The only thing that has changed is a second screen.

Keychain Manager appears to be showing all entries without any problems. The "last changed" date for each entry looks okay (six months to several years back).

What could be causing this? Do I need to be worried?

I'm running a Macbook pro 15 (Late 2011) with Yosemite.

Comment: Did you try to run Keychain First Aid? It's available in the application menu of Keychain Access (Schlüsselbundverwaltung) in 10.10.2 and beyond.

Comment: @Max thanks! It did have some errors but apparently unrelated to the entries it keeps forgetting. I fixed them anyway, maybe it helps.

Comment: Are they gone from the Keychain Access tool when the system _forgets_ them?

Comment: @MaxRied I'll have to check next time it happens again. It seems as if they are not, though: I see four entries for Google Calendars, all with a created date in May last year